# Avoid Join in Spark Scala DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I've to do a calculation based on a JSON file located in a Azure Blob Storage folder. I'm working on Apache Spark on Azure HDInsight.

This folder has a number that it's related with the tracking order. If exist a number higher I've to read the JSON for this folder and discard the folder with lower numbers. For Example, If I have a folder with name 20200501-1 and 20200501-2, I must read 20200501-2.

The solution I've found in Apache Spark is reading the path, and add a column to the data frame as you can see below:

```
val visits = session.read.schema(schema).json(pathData).withColumn("path", input_file_name())
```

And with this path i make some transformation. But, this transformation involve a joins and groups by so, when I run the job with a large dataset in a cluster the Spark Job take a lot of time. Is there a possibility to make a different transformation? or improve my approach.

My transformation work with a dataframe (After add a column) like that:

```
  val visits = Seq(
    ("ITEM4449", 33, "https://somefolder@some.net/20200514-1/somename.json"),
    ("ITEM4450", 16, "https://somefolder@some.net/20200514-1/somename.json"),
    ("ITEM1111", 88, "https://somefolder@some.net/20200514-2/somename.json"),
    ("ITEM4453", 64, "https://somefolder@some.net/20200514-1/somename.json"),
    ("ITEM1111", 12, "https://somefolder@some.net/20200514-1/somename.json")).
    toDF("itemId", "visits", "path")
```

I make this transformation:

```
  def discardByTrackingCode(rawDataFrame: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val visitWithColumn = rawDataFrame.
      withColumn("tracking_version",
        expr("substring(path, 38, 1)"))
    val itemVersionDf = visitWithColumn.
      withColumn("item_version",
        concat(col("ItemId"), lit("_"), col("tracking_version")))
    val versionToTakeDf = itemVersionDf.
      groupBy(col("ItemId").as("item_id_delete")).
      agg(max("item_version").as("item_version"))
    val itemReport = itemVersionDf.join(versionToTakeDf, Seq("item_version"))
    val finalDf = itemReport.select("ItemId", "Visits", "item_version")
    finalDf
  }
```

And obtain the following data frame, which is correct:

```
+--------+------+------------+
|ItemId  |Visits|item_version|
+--------+------+------------+
|ITEM4449|33    |ITEM4449_1  |
|ITEM4450|16    |ITEM4450_1  |
|ITEM1111|88    |ITEM1111_2  |
|ITEM4453|64    |ITEM4453_1  |
+--------+------+------------+
```

There is a most efficient way to make this function work? Beside that. Is possible (or preferable) to looking for the folder using the [Hadoop FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) class?

Comment: extra effort vs extra processing time is a trade-off. time is money. I would do this via linux and put into a directory via cp or symbolic links. it's pre-processing. but i am not sure i would even bother, that said the principle is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use a Window expression:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val window = Window.partitionBy("itemidnumber").orderBy(desc("fileVersion"))

val visits = Seq(
    ("ITEM4449", 33, "https://somefolder@some.net/20200514-1/somename.json"),
    ("ITEM4450", 16, "https://somefolder@some.net/20200514-1/somename.json"),
    ("ITEM1111", 88, "https://somefolder@some.net/20200514-2/somename.json"),
    ("ITEM4453", 64, "https://somefolder@some.net/20200514-1/somename.json"),
    ("ITEM1111", 12, "https://somefolder@some.net/20200514-1/somename.json"))
    .toDF("itemId", "visits", "path")
    .withColumn("itemidnumber", expr("substring(itemId, 5, 4)"))
    .withColumn("fileversion", expr("substring(path, 38, 1)"))
    .withColumn("tracking_version", expr("concat(itemidnumber, substring(path, 38, 1))"))
    .withColumn("row_number", row_number.over(window))
    .filter($"row_number" === 1)    

    display(visits)
```

Output:

[image: Databricks Community Output]